# IOS/Objective-C: Convert UITextAttributeTextColor to NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have some legacy code that uses a variety of UITextAttributes that have been deprecated in favor of NSForegoundColorAttributes.  However, I can't seem to find a straightforward explanation on how to do this update.  Can you just swap one for the other?

Here is my legacy code:

```
NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         kFontNavigationTextColour, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                         [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 2)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                         kFontNavigation, UITextAttributeFont,nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleTextAttributes];
```

Is there a simple algorithm or rule to convert this to the signature?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The "algorithm" is just do it. The docs tell you what to do. Look up each name in turn and do what it tells you.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextattributetextcolor

  Where you have UITextAttributeTextColor, write NSForegroundColorAttributeName instead.
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextattributefont

  Where you have UITextAttributeFont, write NSFontAttributeName instead.

And so on. (I'm a little surprised that Xcode's FixIt feature is not offering to make the substitution for you.)